# Which database must I install in order to run MSDN's T-SQL examples?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

Which databse must I install to be able to run examples in the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

I've downloaded AdventureWorks2008R2 sample databases from [link](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/55926), but examples don't work with any of the AdventureWorks2008R2 databases

thank you

Comment: What errors do you get?  I think the DB you listed should work fine.

Comment: I get errors like "AdventureWorks2008R2 doesn't exists" ( which is true, since none of the sample databases have that exact name ). I also get several "Invalid column name" errors. One particular query  ( from the link I posted ) queries tables HumanResources.Employees and humanResources.EmployeePayHistory. One DB I've downloaded ( named Adventureworks ) does have tables  named HumanResources.Employees and humanResources.EmployeePayHistory, but they have different columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the AdventureWorks2008R2 sample database a while ago - specifically the [one without filestream](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/59211).  I just tried the first few queries from the page you linked to and they return results.

Comment: I tried attaching AdventureWorks2008R2_Data.mdf to the Sql server, but I get an error "Directory lookup for the file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.KJ\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorks2008R2_Log.ldf" failed with the operating system error 3(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105). (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5133)". Any ideas why this error happens?

Comment: Yes, when you attach the file, you'll see both the .mdf and .ldf file listed.  Remove the entry for the .ldf file - SQL Server will rebuild it when you attach the data file.

Comment: Now I get "CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'E:\AdventureWorks2008R2_log.LDF'.
Could not open new database 'AdventureWorks2008R2'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
File activation failure. The physical file name "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.KJ\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorks2008R2_Log.ldf" may be incorrect. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5123)"

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what is happening there.  I followed the instructions on the download page to attach the .mdf using SSMS, and it attached without errors.  Looks like its still looking for the original log file for some reason.

Comment: I reinstalled Sql server, but this time assigned ( during installation process ) to sql server the accounts with greater privileges, and as a result I was able to attach a AdventureWorks2008R2_Data.mdf ( have to remove the .ldf file before it worked). And for some reason I am now able to run the examples - yay. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

the file is the wrong version.

The server supports version 661 and earlier.

The file version is 705

Looking for earlier version.